# backup SQL Server 2014 tables to Excel using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, sql-server-2014

My goal is to have an SSIS package that will export multiple tables from my SQL Sever 2014 DB to one Excel file.

I have got it working but the way I have it setup seems awfully difficult and silly. I checked online but can't find a "better" way to do it so I am posting here hoping someone can either validate what I am doing or slap me to the right direction.

First the Excel file configuration:

- I have an expression variable that points to file with the current date in the name. Like this: `"C:\\backups" + "\\" +  ((DT_WSTR,4)DATEPART("yyyy",@[System::StartTime]) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("mm",  @[System::StartTime]) ,2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("dd",  @[System::StartTime]) ,2)) + ".xlsx"` -> `C:\backups\20180119.xlsx`
- I have a Microsoft Excel 2013 connection where `ExcelFilePath` is set to the above variable.

Then, I have multiple containers, one for each table I want to backup, that all do this:

- `Execute SQL Task` on the Excel connection that executes the SQL:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE `table_name`
  (
      `col1` LONGTEXT,
      `col2` LONGTEXT,
      ...
  )
  ```

  My understanding is that I have to do this because there is a new Excel file for each day so I need to create the table before I can write to it.
- `Data Flow` task with:

  1. `OLE DB Source` pulling from a table in my SQL Server 2014 DB
  2. `Data Conversion` to convert all `varchar` (`string [DT_STR]`) fields to `Unicode string [DT_WSTR]`
  3. `Excel Destination` to the file from the Excel connection

While this all works I have a few issues with it:

1. I have many (20) tables I am exporting like this and managing all the `CREATE TABLE` and `Data Conversions` is a PITA
2. **No matter what I try I cannot get the package to save/write any column that has more than 255 characters. I either have to exclude it from the `Data Flow` or use a `Derived Column` to extract the first 255 characters.**
3. I don't know all the mappings for SQL Server column types to SSIS column types to Excel column types so I just use `LONGTEXT` for everything. I wish it would just use the best column type based on the input data.
4. I just think this seems unnecessarily complicated for what I need to do.

I just need a way to dump 20 tables to 1 Excel file. Is there another way?

Comment: Dumping a database to excel seems like a really bizarre requirement. Why do you need this data in excel like this at all?

Comment: For historical purposes. We have very limited space on our DB and we cannot add more. So I cannot take backups of the tables into archive or history tables or something. So I have to dump the tables somewhere. Dumping to CSV is easier but the files are huge. Excel files are smaller which is why we wanted to dump to Excel. Plus, that way if anyone needed they could quickly open a previous Excel dump file and see what they need in Excel.

Comment: Any other suggestions to do what we need is welcome and appreciated.

Comment: Why not just make a database backup? They are way smaller than an excel file. Then you can restore it whenever you need to view the historical information. Or get some disc space on your sql server. This sounds like it is probably not a very large database which would leave me really concerned when disc space is at such a premium for a system that needs disc space to function correctly.

Comment: Adding disk space is not an option. Trust me, I tried. I will check into the DB backup but one of the reasons we like the Excel file is then anyone can open the Excel file and view previous data as needed.

Comment: MY other question would be are you dumping the data from your database at regular intervals or something? Why not keep the data in the database and then use date ranges to query the data when needed. Everything about this just sounds horribly wrong.

Comment: I have limited space. I can't keep historical information in the DB.

Comment: LOL. I feel your pain but seriously....that is absurd. Disc space is far cheaper than your salary to come up with a crazy solution to a problem that could be solved with just adding another disc to the sql server. I don't what to tell you. You are stuck in a pretty crappy spot.

Comment: I'm surprised that the Excel files are smaller than a CSV. CSV is just a flat file without application overhead like Excel. I would output to a CSV and then compress the files in the same ETL. If you can get the PK of the last entry, you can use this to pick up from where it left off and reduce the amount of data being backed up.

Comment: @tonyd Yes, a compressed CSV is smaller but you lose the benefit of being able to open the Excel file quickly for analysis when you need. With the compressed ZIP you'd have to extract and then open in Excel.